# Updating the Created By field in a Sharepoint list using SOAP interface

Tags: soap, read-only

I have a page that displays items from a Sharepoint list, and add items to that list. The page does this by sending requests to the Sharepoint SOAP service.

I would like to overwrite the `Created By` field when someone adds an item to the Sharepoint list, but I have not been able to.

List Update Request Example

```
<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>
  <Field Name='Title'>This Updates</Field>
  <Field Name='Author'>1;#N. Ame</Field> <!-- I have tried many values here -->
</Method>
```

A new request is added to the list, and the `Title` field has the correct value, but the `Author` (`Created By`) field uses the Group the app pool is using.

I have seen examples of updating the `Author`/`Created By` value using the Sharepoint Client, but I would prefer not to mix interfaces, or completely rewrite this page using the Sharepoint Client unless updating the `Created By` field is not possible via the SOAP service.

[Updating Created By field using Sharepoint client](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tadd/archive/2008/05/22/updating-the-created-by-and-modified-by-columns-in-sharepoint-lists.aspx)

Note: People accessing this page will have already provided their AD credentials, which are used to define what Persons or Groups are valid for the Sharepoint list `Created By` field.

Comment: Are you sure that the ID for that person is 1? Each site collection has a different User Information List.

Comment: That was just an example. I've read the exact Author value for an item using the Sharepoint SOAP service and pasted the text exactly into the value field, ID and all.